# Unable to access SQL Server on the Host Machine from SQL Server Management Studio in the Guest VM

Tags: sql-server, vmware-workstation, virtual-network

Using VMware Workstation 15, should I be using host-only for my scenario below?

I need to access SQL Server, hosted on a Windows 10 host, from a Windows 10 Guest VM,
**without** giving the Guest VM access to the internet/resources on the physical network in which the host machine is situated.

Currently unable to access SQL Server on the Host from SQL Server Management Studio in the Guest VM.
I am able to ping Host➡️Client, and not Host⬅️Client.

Guest VM's Network Adapter set to Host-only.
Tried disabling the firewall on both host and guest and still unable to connect.
Bridge and NAT seem to give internet access to the Guest VM.
Thus I did not use it.

If there is a duplicate post for this, will greatly appreciate having the link posted here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I should check on the SQL Server services. Also, what kind of error you're getting when trying to connect from guest VM?

Comment: Error is "No such host is known". I have SQL Server and Browser running on the host. Also allowed ports 1433 and 1434.

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/359470/connecting-to-sql-server-instance-on-vm-via-host-only-network?rq=1

Comment: Have you already tried using IP address instead of hostname?

Comment: @HumbertoCastellon tried the IP address instead of hostname to no avail.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how VMWare workstation goes about how it does things, but the only way I can think of to do what you're asking would be for VMWare Workstation to create a network adapter specific to the hosted VMs, allow the guest VM to only access the hosting computer through that adapter, and to make sure that SQL server TCP/IP is set up to listen on the VMWare adapter.